# How to upload a file to google drive api with uploadType=resumable

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api

I tried uploading a file following the parameters for resumable upload type, got status 200 (OK), but the file was not uploaded.

- Status view

> ```
> GENERAL
> Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable
> Request Method: POST
> Status Code: 200 
> Remote Address:
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
> ```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

-This is the structure of my code, I will be grateful

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    },
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({mimeType: "image/png", name: "sample" }),
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    timeout: 60000
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to upload a file with the resumable upload using ajax.
- Your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- In order to achieve the resumable upload, it is requierd to do the following flow.

  1. Create the session for the resumable upload.

     - By this, the location can be retrieved from the response headers as the endpoint. This is used for uploading the data.
  2. Upload the data using the retrieved endpoint.
- In your script, the session can be created. But, unfortunately, the location is not retrieved from the response headers. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In this case, as the next step, it is required to upload the file using the location.
- In your script, the file content is not shown. So in this answer, as a sample, I added the file input and button tags as HTML.

#### Modified script:

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="resumableUpload()">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

const getData = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (file) {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = f => resolve({filename: file.name, mimeType: file.type, fileSize: file.size, data: f.target.result});
      fr.onerror = err => reject(err);
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } else {
      resolve({});
    }
  });

async function resumableUpload() {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  const file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  const fileObj = await getData(file);
  if (Object.keys(fileObj).length == 0) {
    console.log("No file.");
    return;
  }

  // 1. Create the session for the resumable upload..
  const metadata = {mimeType: fileObj.mimeType, name: fileObj.filename};
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + accessToken);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      },
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
      success: function (data, _, r) {
        const location = r.getResponseHeader("location");

        // 2. Upload the data using the retrieved endpoint.
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Range", `bytes 0-${fileObj.fileSize - 1}\/${fileObj.fileSize}`);
          },
          url: location,
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
          },
          error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          },
          async: true,
          data: fileObj.data,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          timeout: 60000
        });
        
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      async: true,
      data: JSON.stringify(metadata),
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      timeout: 60000
    });
}  
</script>
```

#### Note:

- In this script, I modified your script.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Perform a resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike, I have implemented it and it has worked correctly for me, I would like to know how to detect the requirements with better precision, do you have any additional guide that you can give me?

Comment: @Vilmcode Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the additional guide, I'm not sure about it. I could know how to use this at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) I apologize for this.